# How to get the location of the directory where the .jar file is present in?

Tags: jar, directory, location

I am trying to read some image files from a folder where the .jar file is being run from. I want to know how to get the path of the directory. I'm trying to do something like this.

```
protected void updateLabel(String name){
    File f = new File("*path where the .jar file is being run from/tmspictures/" + name + ".jpg");
    if(f.exists()){
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("*path where the .jar file is being run from/tmspictures/" + name + ".jpg);
        Image img = icon.getImage(); 
        Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(lbl_pic.getWidth(), lbl_pic.getHeight(),  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        icon = new ImageIcon(newimg);
        lbl_pic.setIcon(icon);
        lbl_pic.setText(null);
    }
    else{
        lbl_pic.setText("Image not found");
        lbl_pic.setIcon(null);
    }
}
```

So if the jar file is being run from `C:/Users/xerof_000/Desktop/TMS.jar` then the pictures should be read from `C:/Users/xerof_000/Desktop/tmspictures/image.jpg` I found one way on stackoverflow but that also returns the file name with the directory. And I don't want to trim that part off and then use the URL. Could someone suggest a simple and easy way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just use the path `./tmspictures/image.jpg` and it will work. Running a jar file sets the working directory to the path where the jar sits, so you can move from there.